# /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/89/jl/res/values/values.xml(4): > error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

While compiling Xamarin Forms for Android platform, I'm getting the following errors regarding the lp/jl files:

> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/89/jl/res/values/values.xml(4):
> > error APT1000: Found tag id where item is expected
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/71/jl/res/values/values.xml(35):
> > error APT1000: Attribute "imageAspectRatioAdjust" already defined with
> > incompatible format.
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/140/jl/res/values/values.xml(36):
> > error APT1000: Original attribute defined here.
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/71/jl/res/values/values.xml(48):
> > error APT1000: Attribute "buttonSize" already defined with
> > incompatible format.
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/140/jl/res/values/values.xml(49):
> > error APT1000: Original attribute defined here.
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/71/jl/res/values/values.xml(56):
> > error APT1000: Attribute "colorScheme" already defined with
> > incompatible format.
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > /Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/obj/Release/lp/140/jl/res/values/values.xml(57):
> > error APT1000: Original attribute defined here.
> > [/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj]
> > Done Building Project
> > "/Users/runner/work/1/s/***_xamarin.Android/***_xamarin.Android.csproj"
> > (PackageForAndroid target(s)) -- FAILED.

when I'm overwriting that files with values.xml of different language it's working but every time i'm doing "Clean Solution" I need to do that again and again. my app is English only and i don't understand from where values.xml of other languages coming from.

Can someone explain from where that files coming to the obj directory? why the error happens and how can I fix this?

Comment: You could refer the reply from this similar issue https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184792/error-apt1000-found-tag-id-where-item-is-expected-apt1000-swlog-android

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT After changing it i am getting different error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  XML document must contain a root level element. Miscellaneous Files xamarin.Android\obj\Release\100\lp\124\jl\res\values-b+sr+Latn\values.xml 1

Comment: Try to create a new blank project to check if the error still exists .